# Accessing Hidden Unordered Lists in CodeIgniter Using CSS/JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, css, codeigniter, zurb-foundation

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to web development.

**Scenario**: I'm making an event based calendar using CodeIgniter. It works great on a desktop/tablet sized window, and I've made a mobile version using Foundation 2.0 by Zurb. It looks great, but there's a problem I'm facing.

**Problem**: In the mobile version, when the calendar generates, I'm needing to hide the `<ul>`s (that display the events in the desktop version) in the mobile version. Then I need to be able to call the `<ul>`s when the `day_listing`s (which are the date numbers on the calendar) are selected/clicked/etc.

Here is how the calendar class generates a date and its events:

```
<td>
   <span class="day_listing">7</span>
      <ul class="event_list">
         <li class="event_type" id="26">Event 1</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="27">Event 2</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="28">Event 3</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="29">Event 4</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="30">Event 5</li>
      </ul>
</td>
```

Here is the code that I am trying to work with:

```
{cal_cell_content}
   <span class="day_listing">{day}</span><ul class="event_list">{content}</ul>
{/cal_cell_content}

{cal_cell_content_today}
   <span class="today_day_listing">{day}</span><ul class="event_list">{content}</ul>
{/cal_cell_content_today}
```

**Note**: This is what you **need** to work with.

**Question**: What method(s) do I need to use (e.g. CSS/JavaScript/PHP/etc.) to hide the `<ul>`s properly when the calendar class generates, and to call them when selected/clicked/etc. on the `day_listing`s?

Thank you so much for all of your help! Below are the resources I'm using that you can reference if you're having trouble knowing what I'm talking about:

- [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com)

Comment: are you sure it is .hide-on-phones {display: !important;} not .hide-on-phones {display: none;} ?

Comment: I updated my question to make it clearer/easier to understand. I hope this helps!

Comment: So on phones, you need to hide the `<ul>`, until the `<span class="day-listing">#</span>` is touched (clicked) ?  and then show the `<ul>` when that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    var isMobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (isMobile) {
        $('.event_list').hide(); // setting display:none; on all .event_list <ul> elements

        // attach click event to the <span class="day_listing"> elements
        $('.day_listing').click(function() {
            var $eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list');

            $('.event_list').hide(); // again hide all possibly shown ones before opening the selected one

            $eventList.show(); // setting display:block on sibling <ul> of clicked <span>
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Receiving this error (JavaScript: Error undefined TypeError: 'undefined'is not a function) on this line of code `var $eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list');` Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Foundation mobile.css (there is no foundation.css that I could find) sets `display:block!important` with the `hide-on-phones` class. It's possible that the ul's are not actually hidden, but are overflowing to a part of the page that isn't visible in the default viewable area (which is why they appear when resized).

That aside, it's not clear what you want. You state that it is working early in the question, then state it's not working... As always, seeing more of your code would be helpful.

To hide the ul's properly, use js:

```
document.getElementById('ulID').style.display="none"
```

you can access its' url via

```
document.getElementById('ulID').href
```

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) would make some of this stuff easier; might be worth looking into.

---

edit:

So this is still confusing me: your ul's don't have the `hide-on-phones` class; is that being set by Foundation?

Also, are you trying to hide the events and have them show when the day is clicked on? e.g.

```
<td>
   <span class="day_listing">7</span>
      <ul class="event_list">
         <li class="event_type" id="26">Event 1</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="27">Event 2</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="28">Event 3</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="29">Event 4</li>
         <li class="event_type" id="30">Event 5</li>
      </ul>
</td>
```

the events are hidden by default then when you click on "7" they show? If that is indeed what you want, an example of a jQuery solution using the existing markup generated by calendar:

(as an aside, you'll probably want to use [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) so jQuery doesn't interfere with your other libraries)

```
function itsMobile(){
    jQuery('.event_list').hide();
    jQuery('.day_listing').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
       navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
       navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
       navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)){
           itsMobile(); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Update my answer above. Cheers.

Comment: I've updated my question to make it clearer/easier to understand. Thank you so much for the jQuery snippet! I'll test it, and I'll let you know how it turns out!

Comment: ok, I updated the code again to add a check for mobile browsers. if it is a mobile device, it will hide the ul's and show or hide them when date is clicked.